# npm start error across all react projects on my PC

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-start

**Issue with npm start in React Project**

When attempting to execute `npm start` in any of my React projects, I consistently encounter the following error:

**Expected Behavior:**

I anticipated the React app to launch successfully without encountering the mentioned error.

**Attempts Made:**

I have already undertaken the following troubleshooting steps:

```
npm cache clean -f

rm -rf node_modules

rm package-lock.json
```

Additionally, I have uninstalled Node.js from my machine and reinstalled the latest version. Despite these efforts, the problem persists. Seeking assistance and guidance to resolve this issue. Appreciate any insights or solutions provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the steps to troubleshoot your problem:-

1. Make sure Node is correctly installed to your pc and environment
   variable is correctly configured for node.
2. Your can then use `npm create vite@latest` or `npm create-react-app myapp`.
3. Make sure all the required packages are installed correctly using the `npm install` or `npm i`.
4. For running the app you can use `npm start` or `npm run start` for create-react-app.
   And `npm run dev` for vite.